# How to add custom css file into widget component in ofbiz

Tags: ofbiz

I have a problem with css file in ofbiz.
default css files are loaded from webapp component but i want to add own css file into widget xml file. any one help me to fix the problem with example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean loading new css fiels using Ofbiz?

If so, you can just create a css file and add that path in main decorator/ screen in actions tag as shown below:

```
 <set field="layoutSettings.styleSheets[]" value="/xxx/xxx/xxxx.css" global="true"/>
```

If not, please can you elaborate your question.

Comment: General: You can add css file by using `VisualThemeResource` in theme data.

Comment: You mean, directly as a record in VisualThemeResource entity?